# Disable copy and paste

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, copy-paste

I have used following code to disable copy paste

```
onpaste="return false;" oncut="return false;" oncontextmenu="return false;" oncopy="return false;".
```

This works all fine. I have install "easy-copy" extension in Google Chrome and can still copy paste. Is there a way to disable copy and paste from extensions as well?

I tried to capture all the events to see what even that extension fire to paste but it doesn't fire any even for pasting.

For event capturing, I used following code in chrome console:

```
monitorEvents($0)
```

In short, how to disable copy paste from browser extension? Why do I need this? I have a chat application and some people copy paste to spam.

Comment: "I have a chat application and some people copy paste to spam." But what if some good person wants to copy or paste something? Could you mitigate the spam attack differently (server side blocking multiple calls, etc.)

Comment: We have all other methods implemented. Like ban ip, only 3 messages/time limit, filtering bad words, no repeat same message etc. However, if there are 3-4 spammers they can still by pass all that by working together ;). For other good users, we never provided copy-paste option to them and they never complained.

Comment: As you can see in the source code of that extension, it directly accesses/modifies DOM of the page. To prevent that you can draw the entire UI of your app using Canvas API, so there will be only a picture in DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In short, how to disable copy paste from browser extension?

I don't think this is possible from the page Javascript, because extensions run at a higher trust level than the webpage. They can do things that webpages cannot such as change the browser's own behavior.

In my opinion the best way to handle this is server-side.  Give each post a spam score determined by relevant factors such as frequency of posts from the same user, duplicate content in posts, external links only, downvotes from other users...  If a post exceeds a spam score limit, don't show it to other users.  You could still show it to the poster herself if you want to make it harder for spammers to determine whether their spam is actually getting through.

Disabling copy-paste for all users seems heavy handed to me.

Comment: Seems valid. Do you have a source for this claim?

Comment: @Pavlo Common sense in my opinion. Can a webpage block scripts from all domains?  An extension can do that.  Can a webpage change your browser security settings?  An extension can. Or inspect all https traffic from all pages.  Or see and save all entered passwords....  Not sure why anyone would doubt that extensions run at a higher trust level.

Comment: How do some websites then detect "ad-blocker" extensions and pop-ups to disable or they won't serve. Can't we do same for copy-paste extensions to detect and alert user?

Comment: @user3404047 the website javascript knows where ads should be displayed, so when it checks that area of the page and doesn't find ads, it *guesses* that an ad-blocker is running. It doesn't actually know it for sure.  As for your question, I've expanded my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

[Testing it on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZR9C.png)

You can try using

```css
* {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;/*IE,etc*/
  -moz-user-select: none; /*Mozzila Firefox*/
}
```

```html
<h2>Copy Me if you Can </h2>
```

On my end this works, try it removing `user-select: none;` and seeing if has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm just some general thoughts here. Trying to block this kind of operation is never going to fully work because browsers behave differently and ultimately the behaviour can be circumvented no matter what you do.

But in terms of making it more awkward why don't you just limit how often they can press the submit button in a given time frame. Or limit the max text size of the textbox. Better still as per previous comment on the server restrict it this will give you the security that no client side validation will. Any client side validation can only hinder attempts but not truly prevent it.

Actually another thing you can do is have an intercepting javascript function that will check for repeated text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please have a look to my comment in response to rap-2-h comment in the question.

Comment: I don't see how preventing copy and paste is going to stop multiple people. You should also be able to prevent multiple people spamming server side because the message is the same surely you just look at the previous messages before adding it regardless of who sent it.

Comment: Adding a space or a comma after pasting makes it different than the previous message. Or any other addition to previous message.